# How can i break a foreach statement, echo something else and then continue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, break, continue

I am getting two different arrays arrays of data from MSQL database, first array from my blog post table containing 15 rows/items, and the second array from advert table containing 3 rows/item. i want to foreach the first 5 set of data from blog post table(the first array), then foreach 1 (one) from advert table (second array) and continue from where i stopped in the first array with another 5 item and one from the first array, just like that. 
Please help me come up with PHP code on how to do that.
thank you.

Comment: You might start by telling us for what programming language you use

Comment: Please i need PHP code to do that

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: foreach blog_array where i%5 == 0 etc. etc. where are your tut books ?

Answer (score 0):

use modulo.

you will have a count with `mssql_num_rows`, then iterate a counter, say `$i`

then in foreach($rows)..:

```
$i = 0; $count = mssql_num_rows($result);
foreach($rows as $blog) {
    if($i > 0 && $i++ % 5 == 0) {
        $advert = array_shift($adverts_array);
        // process $advert
    }
    // process $blog here
}
```

Comment: if you wish to also start with an add, remove `$i > 0` clause

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I tried the above scripts it outputs 5 from the posts array as expected, the problem now is dat its does no echo the array values of the advertisement array and when I use foreach for the advertisement array it prints all the advertisement content before continuing that of the post array, please how do I fix this??

Comment: couldnt say why from the info youve provided.. but you have two resultsets to iterate right? then simply process the first advert @ count 5, second advert @ count 10 etc. thats why the comment says 'take one(!)'

Answer (score 0):

The code assumes arrays are indexed starting from `0`.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  // Output and/or otherwise process $post
  if (++$i % 5 == 0) {
    $advertisements[$i / 5 - 1] // Output and/or process advertisement
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I tried the above scripts it outputs 5 from the posts array as expected, the problem now is dat its does no echo the array values of the advertisement array and when I use foreach for the advertisement  array it prints all the advertisement content before continuing that of the post array, please how do I fix this??